# Is it possible to omit a type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm translating a very old and big Java server to Kotlin, and I'm trying to make as few logic changes as possible during the conversion. I'm looking for a way to translate this snippet of Java code without fundamentally changing it.

Consider the following toy code:

```kotlin
interface Pet

class Dog : Pet
class Cat : Pet

class PetSitter<T : Pet> {
  fun walk(pet: T) {}
}

fun main() {
  val sitters: Array<PetSitter<*>> =
      arrayOf(PetSitter<Cat>(), PetSitter<Dog>())

    sitters[0].walk(Cat()) // Type mismatch.
                           // Required: Nothing
                           // Found: Cat
}
```

This fails to compile with the message `Type mismatch: inferred type is Cat but Nothing was expected`.

In Java the following works fine:

```java
PetSitter[] sitters = ... // Note: PetSitter's generic is omitted
sitters[0].walk(new Cat());
```

Is it possible to similarly define a `Array<PetSitter>` (with no pet generic) in Kotlin? Or some other way to make the parameter type for `PetSitter<*>.walk` to be `Pet` instead of `Nothing`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, this is called a raw type. It is only supported by necessity for backward compatibility, and it is discouraged to ever use, because it defeats the purpose of using generics. For the same reason, Kotlin forbids it outright because it doesn't have a pre-generics version of the language it must support.

The equivalent of using a raw type is to cast the types to be permissive. This requirement is to force you to consider if the cast is appropriate.

```
(sitters[0] as PetSitter<Cat>).walk(Cat())
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It sounds like it's not possible to do without specifying a specific subtype of `Pet`, but you gave me another idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70114733/2875073

Answer (score 0):

Update: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70114733/2875073 which is simpler.

It seems Kotlin doesn't allow raw types, but it looks like a work-around is to cast my instance of Pet to `Pet` and then make a `when` case enumerating each subtype and casting `sitters[0]` for each case:

```kotlin
val myPet: Pet = Cat()
when (myPet) {
    is Dog -> (sitters[0] as PetSitter<Dog>).walk(myPet)
    is Cat -> (sitters[0] as PetSitter<Cat>).walk(myPet)
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the implementation of PetSitter expects a certain type. In your example PetSitter doesn't utilize the generics in the first place, so it wouldn't matter. But your code as shown in Java is potentially unsafe if the generics were being used, and that code would only be safe if you were sure the PetSitter in index 0 was in fact a Cat PetSitter.

Comment: That's correct. For example, if I used `sitters[1]` which was an instance of `PetSitter<Dog>`, and passed an instance of `Cat` it would fail. But this server has existing business logic that guarantees they match up. It's just the type system that doesn't realize it.

Comment: If you're trying to handle a Pet of any kind, it would be simpler to do this: `(sitters[0] as PetSitter<Pet>).walk(Dog())` instead of a when statement.

Comment: Haha you're completely right. the when statement is entirely unnecessary, thanks for simplifying.

Comment: I updated your answer with your suggestion on this thread and marked it as the answer. Thanks again for helping me with this!